# "Add New Item" dialog for Web Application Project doesn't include "Web Form"?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

VS2008
Web Application Project

My "Add New Item" dialog doesn't include "Web Form".  Here is a list of the items which are included in the Web category:

ADO.NET Data Service
ASP.NET Server Control
JScript File
Style Sheet

That's all.  No Web Form.  No User Control.  Etc.

How do I get restore my templates so that I have all of them?

Some things I've tried:

- Changing my "User item templates location" from "C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Templates\ItemTemplates" to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates"
- devenv /installvstemplates
- devenv /setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you select to install the "Web Developer" or "Web Designer" portion of Visual Studio upon installation?

Comment: Hrm.. maybe this is to blame.  I recently changed editions of VS.  That might be about when my "Web Form" disappeared, actually.  What could I do with my current instance of VS to authoritatively get an answer to your question?

Comment: hmm, I would go to add/remove programs and change the installation, and then see if you selected the "web designer" portion.  if not, just select it and continue on.

Comment: I recently switched to Visual Studio Team System 2008 Development Edition.  That must have been when I shot myself in the foot.  I just now modified the installation to include the "Visual Web Developer" feature (I should have included it the first time).  The problem is solved.  "Web Form" appears as it should (along with everything else).  Many thanks.

Comment: I've done the same thing before, where I thought I was "saving" space and ended up wondering where everything went.  Glad you got it solved.